# Puzzling validation error after upgrading from Grails 2.2.5 to 4.0.11

Tags: grails

A method which was working for a long time in Grails 2.2.5 has broken after moving to 4.0.11 with a validation error on saving, and the error is a puzzle to me. I have a domain class 'Decline' which has one of its properties 'user', which is of domain class user. As part of the save process I assign the currently logged in user to this property:

```
Decline decline = new Decline()
decline.policy = policy
decline.declineTime = new Date()
decline.field = field
decline.cause = reason
decline.user = User.getUser()
decline.save(flush:true)
```

This was working fine in 2.2.5 but now I get the following validation error:

`Field error in object 'myapp.pei.Decline' on field 'user.userType': rejected value [DIRECT_CLIENT]; codes [myapp.User.userType.nullable.error.myapp.pei.Decline.user.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.error.user.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.error.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.error.myapp.UserType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.error,user.userType.nullable.error.myapp.pei.Decline.user.userType,user.userType.nullable.error.user.userType,user.userType.nullable.error.userType,user.userType.nullable.error.myapp.UserType,user.userType.nullable.error,myapp.User.userType.nullable.myapp.pei.Decline.user.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.user.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.userType,myapp.User.userType.nullable.myapp.UserType,myapp.User.userType.nullable,user.userType.nullable.myapp.pei.Decline.user.userType,user.userType.nullable.user.userType,user.userType.nullable.userType,user.userType.nullable.myapp.UserType,user.userType.nullable,nullable.myapp.pei.Decline.user.userType,nullable.user.userType,nullable.userType,nullable.myapp.UserType,nullable]; arguments [userType,class myapp.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]`

There are two things which are puzzling about this. Firstly, and more importantly, this appears to be an error saving the User object. But why is it even trying to save the User object? I have assigned an existing User object which it should be using. Secondly, the specific error is 'rejected value [DIRECT_CLIENT]' for field 'user.userType', but the error message is that this field cannot be null. So it's rejecting a value but telling me it cannot be null! The value, incidentally, is of a UserType enum defined thus:

```
public enum UserType {
    ADMIN_USER,ADMIN_OWNER_USER,SUPER_USER,BROKER,DIRECT_CLIENT

}
```

I wonder what change from version 2.2.5 to 4 (or maybe 3) could have caused this?

Comment: I vaguely remember something about save-time validation changing since grails 2; I think things are deeply validated now whereas they weren't before.  As a diagnosis (not a fix), what happens when you add `deepValidate:false` to your `.save()` call?

Comment: According to the 2.2.5 docs, deepValidate was already the default. But clearly something changed, as the identical code behaves differently between versions. I do think there is a problem there, as even with deepValidate as true, the associated User object should not cause a validation error, as it doesn't if I do 'user.save()' directly on the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was some change in behaviour of deepValidate between Grails 2.x and 4.x which is causing this, although I don't see why validation of the associated User object should be failing when it can actually be saved OK separately. But what got me past this issue was to set the following in the mapping block for Decline:

```
user cascadeValidate: 'none'
```

This ensures that when the Decline object is saved it does not attempt to validate the User as well.